# Angular, any library for Org Chart?

Tags: web-apps, library

I want to see if you guys are familiar with any Org Chart library for Angularjs,
what I am trying to do is not complex, but should be with Angular and I don't want to do it from scratch, I need any library, and if its possible, responsible but not necessary.

I need to achieve something like this:

http://jointjs.com/demos/org

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript/Angular](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including Org Charts. Here is an [example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/mi2u0kdo).

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

[image: screenshot]

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Wow, $2k(!). Does the community license require attribution, such as branding?

Comment: No. The community license has no requirements such as branding. We provide the full version as the community license as long as the entity using it qualifies.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (+1). Could you please post a URL to the license, or explanation of who qualifies for the community license? This looks very well worth investigating.

Comment: http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense#faq
Individual developers or up to five users at companies with annual gross revenue below $1 million USD.

Answer (score 1):

Another commercial alternative to consider is [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml):

It provides all the bells and whistles you could ever wish for in organization chart scenarios. See this simple [online demo](http://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/orgchart/index.html) for an example of what it can do.

The library has great integration with Angular and AngularJS and you can make use of a complete TypeScript integration if you want to. This is highlighted in [these demos](http://live.yworks.com/demos/#angular).

Here is what it can look like, but the real power of the library is the customizability. You can change literally *anything* to exactly cover your specific requirements:

[image]

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates that library, however I do not represent my employer, here.</sup>